# What is the difference between MiniTest's assert_in_delta and assert_in_epsilon methods?

Tags: ruby, minitest, approximate

Here is [documentation for `assert_in_delta`](http://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_in_delta):

> ```
> assert_in_delta(exp, act, delta = 0.001, msg = nil) public
> ```
>
> For comparing Floats. Fails unless exp and act are within delta of each other.
>
> ```
> assert_in_delta Math::PI, (22.0 / 7.0), 0.01
> ```

And here is the [documentation for `assert_in_epsilon`](http://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_in_epsilon)

> ```
> assert_in_epsilon(a, b, epsilon = 0.001, msg = nil) public
> ```
>
> For comparing Floats. Fails unless exp and act have a relative error less than epsilon.

These look very similar; what exactly is the difference? When would you use one method over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key difference is:

- `assert_in_delta` is for **absolute** errors.
- `assert_in_epsilon` is for **relative** errors.

These are two different types of [approximation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error):

> The absolute error is the magnitude of the difference between the exact value and the approximation.
>
> The relative error is the absolute error divided by the magnitude of the exact value.

---

`assert_in_delta` is easiest to understand, and will most commonly be used in tests.

In the documentation's example: `assert_in_delta Math::PI, (22.0 / 7.0), 0.01`, this assertion will **pass** because `22.0/7 - Math::PI == 0.001264...`, which is less than the allowed `delta` of `0.01`.

---

(From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Uses_of_relative_error))

`assert_in_epsilon` is often used to compare approximations of numbers of wildly differing size.

For example, approximating the number `1,000` with an absolute error of `3` is, in most applications, much worse than approximating the number `1,000,000` with an absolute error of `3`; in the first case the relative error is `0.003` and in the second it is only `0.000003`.

To write this example in `MiniTest`, suppose we have an array of two values which we want to check are "approximately equal to" `1,000` and `1,000,000` respectively. We could write the following:

```
# Using the default `epsilon` of 0.001
assert_in_epsilon(1_000, actual[0])
assert_in_epsilon(1_000_000, actual[1])
```

This would be functionally equivalent to writing:

```
assert_in_delta(1_000, actual[0], 1)
assert_in_delta(1_000_000, actual[1], 1000)
```